# JavaMailSender не подключается к SMTP Goggle

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, smtp, gmail

Не подключается к узлу SMTP.

Описание ошибки:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2197)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
```

Файл конфигурации application.properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=********@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=********
```

Comment: IMAP в настройках почты включен?

Comment: да и вообще лучше ознакомиться с данной статьей - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

Comment: Спасибо, tls не включил.